# Win 8 Metro App won't suspend correctly / Cert Kit fails

Tags: javascript, windows-8, dom-events, microsoft-metro, app-certification-kit

My Javascript/HTML based Metro App is finished that far, but I can't get it to suspend correctly.

The taskmanager and the Cert Kit are telling me that my App is not getting suspended.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, since as far as I understood it, I just have to set the `EventListener` and the function called this way has to exit fast enough.

I tried setting the `EventListener` in different ways:

```
app.addEventListener("suspending", onsuspend, false);

app.addEventListener("checkpoint", onsuspend, false);

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {}
```

I have left the `onsuspend` Function either completely empty or just wrote this in it

```
var stateObject = new Object();

app.sessionState.stateObject = stateObject;
```

without additional code.

It's just a simple game that I draw directly on the Canvas, I don't use any other resources likes pictures or stuff that I might need to release...

And yes I realised a Debug App won't get suspended until I use the "suspend" button in Visual Studio.

---

All right, so now the Windows App Certification Kit validates my App without any form of suspend/resume handling, like I had it set up on the first try...

So I still have no Idea what went wrong before.

Comment: Allright, so now the Windows App Certification Kit validates my App without any form of susped/resume Handling, like I had it set up on the first try...

So I still have no Idea what went wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass WACK with something very simple.  Try for example ...

```
function resuming() {
    console.log('resuming'); // not needed just for debugging
}


function suspending() {
    console.log('suspending');  // not needed just for debugging
}

var webapp = Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication;

webapp.addEventListener("resuming", resuming, false);
webapp.addEventListener("suspending", suspending, false);
```